# Manual Demonstration Circuit for 74HC595 Shift Register

Tags: debounce, 74hc595

I am trying to create a manual demonstration circuit for a 74HC595 shift register. Se my circuit below. The problem I am having is that I am only getting a +0.7V signal to the data, clock, and latch pins of the 74HC595 when one of the buttons are pushed. The `S4 RESET` switch works fine (normally high at 5V, press switch to bring down to 0V), however `S1`, `S2`, and `S3` do not accomplish the reverse scenario (normally LOW, press switch for HIGH) correctly.  You will note that I am also trying to debounce the switching with a capacity or resistor. I suspect this debouncing set up is creating my problem.

Does anybody have any advice on how to create a debounced normally LOW, momentarily HIGH switch that switches between 0V and 5V?

[image: 74HC595 Manual Demo Circuit]

Comment: Your gate debouncing looks almost straight out of a very old document. Except for one thing. The Schmitt trigger inverter/buffer such as the 74HC14, which makes it normally low. You may need to add that. You probably need the hysteresis. I haven't attempted to compute resistor and capacitor values, though. But on the referenced document, and where they are using HC parts, they came up with \$82\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ and \$18\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ to go with the \$100\:\textrm{nF}\$ capacitor. Close. But there could be something more to do there, as well. Can you show how you got those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.7V is the base emitter voltage of the transistors.

To verify: Remove the transistors from the circuit.

Fix: Add a resistor (1k to 10k) to the transistor bases.
Better yet: Connect the transistors (with resistor) directly to the switches.

Comment: That was it. Connecting the transistor base to a 1k resistor which is then connected directly to the switch works perfectly. Thanks!